# Only my index.py shows on my local ubuntu server, no other file works

Tags: python, mysql, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I went through this tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04

which is setting up mysql, apache, python to run a local web server on ubuntu.

In the end, my localhost shows index.py but any other python file I create gets a 500 internal server error.

How can I run other python files in my browser?

my index.py which i use server.com to reach

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Turn on debug mode.
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

# Connect to the database.
print('hI')
```

my test.py which i use server.com/test.py to reach

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
copper.project.path = /home/bert/docs/

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print('hids')
```

I also did chmod on the file to 755

Comment: Seriously, don't do this. Use a framework, even a micro one like Flask.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you explain why?